# searching database with keyword in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

i am creating a system that will be tracking the coming in and out documents in an office. The user should be able to view the reports or the record. I have created a simple textbox that will serve as a search tool. The search process should allow the user to select the datagridview using a keyword.

example: if the user search for a record  that has a keyword of "Book" the subject that has a word "book" in it should appear.
example: keyword: book
         displays in datagridview: book of enoch
                                   book shelf
                                   record book

Regardless of the uppercase or lowercase. kinda like GOOGLE

i tried creating a search process but it only shows the exact word and not the statement with the word "Book"

this is my code

```
Try
            connection.Open()

            Dim query As String
            query = "select id,Type_of_Document,Items,Received_From,Received_Date,Remarks,Marginal_Note,Referred_To,Referred_Date,Action_Taken  from tracker.recordtracker where Items = '" & srchtbx.Text & "'"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(DataSet)
            bind.DataSource = DataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bind
            adapter.Update(DataSet)
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Dispose()
        End Try
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.Contains method:

I'm assuming you're looping every row already in the grid:

```
rowValue.ToString.ToLower.Contains(query.ToLower)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
 string upper = "CONVERTED FROM UPPERCASE";
 Console.WriteLine(upper.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
... where Items = '" & srchtbx.Text & "'"
```

you are specifying there must be an exact match to the full string.  To perform a substring search use the LIKE keyword e.g.

```
... WHERE Items LIKE '%" & srchtbx.Text & "%'"
```

More information about SQL LIKE Operator: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp